# All combinations of an associative array in a template string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have this use case where I need to write all combinations of an array into a given template string.

i.e:

```php
// can have as many identifier keys 'A', 'B', 'C', etc
$arr = [
    'A' => [
        // can have as many replacement values
        'A1',
        'A2'
    ],
    'B' => [
        'B1',
        'B2'
    ]

];
$template = 'A B A';
// returns an array of strings like output below
$genStrings = generateStrings($arr, $template); 
// Output
// A1 B1 A1
// A1 B1 A2
// A2 B1 A1
// A2 B1 A2
// A1 B2 A1
// A1 B2 A2
// A2 B2 A1
// A2 B2 A2
```

Any light out there? Been trying to accomplish this all last night, no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: You should exlplode the template, and loop... Please post your tries...

Comment: I'm ready to help you with a possible solution, but indeed, please share your attempts first. Maybe you're not that far off and there's a way to guide you through.

Comment: The use case is much more complex than just exploding the template, I'm trying to obfuscate css selectors given replacements for each element in the selector (this element is a key in that $arr and the replacements are the values), then the solution would require pattern replaces though I have already made some progress here. The reason I'm asking this here is to figure out the minimum logic I need to generate the strings. I have already read something about power sets and this looks like a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a recursive function that combines all possible values for the first item with all possible permutations for the rest.

Note: PHP 7.4 code but this can be easily made compatible with previous versions if needed.

```
/**
 * @param mixed[] $inputArray
 * @param int[]|string[] $template
 * @return mixed[][]
 */
function computePermutations(array $inputArray, array $template): array
{
  $permutations = [];
  $lastPass = count($template) === 1;

  foreach ($inputArray[$template[0]] as $firstPermutation) {
    if ($lastPass) {
      $permutations[] = [$firstPermutation];
    }
    else {
      foreach (computePermutations($inputArray, array_slice($template, 1)) as $restPermutation) {
        $permutations[] = [$firstPermutation, ...$restPermutation];
      }
    }
  }

  return $permutations;
}
```

Usage:

```
$permutations = computePermutations($arr, explode(' ', $template));
$permutationsAsStrings = array_map(fn($permutation) => implode(' ', $permutation), $permutations);

print_r($permutationsAsStrings);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/d4uZc)

Comment: This is a good starting point for me, I'll try extending this solution to when the template is something like "A.abc B#io A#123". I actually would've loved something like: $permutations = computePermutations($arr, "A.abc B#io A#123") and this would return all a string[] of the outputs. I'll mark you as accepted though and work on this :) thanks! :)

Comment: I could help you with that but not sure to follow: what do these `.abc` and `#io` things represent? You'd have to give examples. You could also post this as a new question (and link it here).